# PVob share permission

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

we have multisite UCM. As each VObs are stored in Server's directory, we use to raise to our IT team. They will provide access to shares.

Few IT persons said for PVOB storage share, we do not have to get permission unless we execute some cleartool commands from PVOB.

But today we faced some issues while check-in and one of IT admin asked us to raise request to get PVOB share access.

Whether PVOB share access should be given to limited people or it should be given to all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pvob share access (to its Vob storage) should be granted, with the same perimeter than for the vobs. It is safest that way, in order for all the UCM Vobs to run properly.